# How to access the register name and its index from Qubits in Qiskit SDK 1.0?

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I have QAOA Quantum Circuit.

```python
   qubit_gate_idx={}
   dag = circuit_to_dag(qc)
   for qubit in dag.qubits:
     qubit_gate_idx[qubit] = 0
    
  for vertex in dag.topological_op_nodes():
    if len(vertex.qargs) == 0:
        continue  # Skip vertices with no qargs
    elif len(vertex.qargs) == 1:
        arg0 = vertex.qargs[0]
```

how to access the register name and index from qubits i.e. `Qubit(QuantumRegister(5, 'q'), 0)` in Qiskit SDK 1.0

Answer (score 2):

To see everything that can be accessed in the `Qubit` class, look at the directory `dir`. From the directory, we see that the register and index are stored as private variables. Below is a code snippet showing how to access the desired information.

```
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumRegister, Qubit

qubit = Qubit(QuantumRegister(5, 'q'), 0)
print(dir(qubit))
print("Index:", qubit._index)
print("Register name:", qubit._register.name)
```

The output is

```
['__class__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_hash', '_index', '_register', '_repr']
Index: 0
Register name: q
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. I have Question h to Add my own Noise like depolarising Error  in Qiskit Sdk 1.0 and count it through qiskit_ibm_runtime

Comment: Please start a new question about adding noise, since it is not the same topic as the current question.

Answer (score 2):

To get the location(s) of a qubit in the circuit you can use `QuantumCircuit`'s [`find_bit`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit#find_bit) method as follows:

```python
qubit = vertex.qargs[0]

bit_locations = qc.find_bit(qubit)
print(bit_locations.registers[0][0].name)
print(bit_locations.registers[0][1])
```